# Should I avoid discussing subjects that I am unfamiliar with?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I'm a bit discouraged by the bad reputation that I've gained recently. Whenever I ask a question about a programming language that I'm relatively unfamiliar with, it often brings me a lot of ridicule from the rest of the community (which may be well-deserved, since the amount of ignorance that I have shown may in fact be unacceptable).

Should I stop asking questions about programming languages that I am unfamiliar with, and focus on just one programming language instead? I feel quite discouraged by all of the downvotes that I've gotten as a result of my lack of expertise in certain subjects.

One recurring pattern that I've noticed is that questions are often downvoted if they demonstrate relative unfamiliarity with a particular subject. I'm reasonably familiar with the JavaScript and Java programming languages, but I'm relatively unfamiliar with Bash, Lua, Python, Haxe, and C# - therefore, my relative unfamiliarity with these subjects will tarnish my reputation, since everyone expects me to be well-informed about every subject that I have ever discussed here. If one of my questions is downvoted, I usually take it as an indication that the rest of the community is appalled by my apparent ignorance of a particular subject, and deems me to be worthy of ridicule. Perhaps I'm being overly-sensitive, but I find all of these negative reviews to be quite upsetting.

Now I'm faced with a dilemma: Should I stop asking questions about subjects that I'm relatively unfamilar with (in order to avoid being downvoted), and only discuss topics that I am  familiar with, or should I leave Stack Overflow entirely, assuming that my contributions have been mostly unconstructive and harmful?

Comment: I'm aware that the tone of my question may seem excessively pessimistic - but that's mainly because I'm beginning to doubt my overall usefulness as a contributor to Stack Overflow (and therefore, my apparent lack of usefulness to the rest of society in general).

Comment: *Which technologies are you currently using to develop an active software project?*  Those are the technologies that you should be attempting to answer questions for.  Ignore the rest; you need your finger on the pulse of a technology to effectively answer questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I suggest avoiding all *discussion*, regardless of the subject. Stack Overflow doesn't really do discussion. I know you're going to quibble over the fact that "it is just a word" and "I really meant 'asking questions'", but words are important because they have meaning. Lots of people ask discussion-based questions, or prompts for discussion masquerading as questions. These are the questions that get downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't referring to opinion-based discussions. I know that these types of discussions don't usually lead to objective answers, so they aren't usually useful here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> One recurring pattern that I've noticed is that questions are often downvoted if they demonstrate relative unfamiliarity with a particular subject.

That's really not why you're being downvoted. People are commenting on your questions to explain downvotes.

1. [How can I find all indices of a value in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17539140/1288) is a reasonable question to ask, but you don't show any attempt of your own.
2. [How can I keep track of equivalent functions in different programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17665043/1288) has the same problem, but as you pointed out, you were posting an answer yourself at the time you asked the question.  I think it's just a really impractical problem, and probably would have gotten downvotes even if you had tried to solve it in Java or JavaScript.

Comment: I was really taken by surprise when I realized that "How can I keep track of equivalent functions in different programming languages" was considered a "bad" question. This is a problem that I often face when designing source-to-source compilers (and therefore it seemed like a reasonable question to me). But source-to-source compiler design is a relatively obscure subject, so I can understand why the question was unfavorably received.

Comment: A simple piece of paper would suffice.  Or a spreadsheet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It would certainly suffice, if I were working with just a few different programming languages. If I needed to keep track of dozens equivalent functions in dozens of different programming languages, then I *might* need to use a database of some kind.

Comment: For comparison, look at the big yawn this self-answered question got: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188903/102937.  In my experience, crowdsourcing a question gets much better answers; that's partly why self-answered questions have such a hard time of it.  The only way a self-answered question gets any respect is if it's good enough to post on your blog, but then, y'now, you'd post it on your blog.

Comment: @AndersonGreen It might help if you explain why you're storing equivalent functions. Are you writing some super generic program that can be converted to any language? That sounds like a monumental task

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, that's exactly why I asked the question.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I admit i'm relatively new to programming but *why* are you doing that

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm actually working on a domain-specific programming language that is intended to be compiled into as many different programming languages as possible. It's a very interesting concept, since it allows me to automatically generate entire software libraries in Ruby, Java, JavaScript, Python, and Lua.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I can see the advantage of that (I was imagining whole programs rather than libraries); good luck with it, I imagine getting the syntax right is going to be the hardest part (the if its got {} in java it needs indentation in python etc etc)

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice advice in your most DV Question: [*Don't denigrate yourself. Do more research.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995696/nested-loops-in-x86-assembly#comment22808339_15995696)

Please, quit the `most hated members of the entire community` self-appointed role, unless you can provide some statistics that prove that.

[BilltheLizard already shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188926/185667) where you're having problems. And to solve them, read the guide [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and **especially** the *Related* articles that you find in that page.

With that "technology" (I mean, knowledge) at hand, I think you'll be able to write even the most n00b Question and increase by numbers the chances of receiving a very good Answer.

Comment: @notify doesn't work in answers. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, how do you say? Reflexive action? :o)

Comment: I'm only calling myself one of the "most-hated" members because Stack Overflow has been draining away my self-esteem - mainly because of my over-sensitivity to criticism. I take Stack Overflow quite seriously, and I'm trying to do as much as I can to be a constructive user.

Comment: @AndersonGreen The net is not a good place if you are over-sensitive to criticism. Downvotes can be very hard for the selfesteem, but you have to not take them for more than what they are. I know exactly how you feel about it, because I feel *exactly* the same. There is a lot of perceived unfairness - why do they upvote the guy with the more rep, when his answer is the same as mine, why do they downvote a reasonable question, etc. You have to let it go, don't take it personal and try to notice when the scale tips the other way and you get the upvotes where a newbie feels (s)he should have 'em.

Comment: @AndersonGreen And remember, the personal (serial) downvotes are removed by the scripts. ;-)